# SSRS Export to word - error: the rectangle is too complex to export to Word

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

There is a report that has been in production for years but now is throwing an error when trying to export it to Word. The error is:

> The Rectangle is too complex to export to Word. 
>   Please group the ReportItems together into rectangles to simplify.

Nothing has changed anywhere, and I cannot find an answer to this anywhere. Can anyone here help?

Comment: Have you checked out [this forum?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f534201a-bb9b-40d8-af7e-a7bfd04208ae/error-on-exporting-to-word?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: I did. But couldn't get something that works for me out of it.